# How to uninstall Jetbrains IDE?

Tags: macos

When news version of Jetbrains IDE is installed previous version does not remove automatically. And currently there are no option (i.e. checkbox) to uninstall old version while installing.

How can one completely uninstall Jetbrains IDE (*like IntelliJ IDEA, PyCharm, WebStorm, RubyMine, PhpStorm, CLion, AppCode, Rider, Data Grip etc.*) in OS X?

Comment: Which versions did you upgrade from and to?

Comment: From **IntelliJ IDEA CE 15** to **IntelliJ IDEA CE 2016**

Answer (score 20):

Move the .app file to the Trash, then manually delete the support folders listed in this [IntelliJ support article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs):

- ~/Library/Preferences/[PRODUCT][VERSION]
- ~/Library/Caches/[PRODUCT][VERSION]
- ~/Library/Application Support/[PRODUCT][VERSION]
- ~/Library/Logs/[PRODUCT][VERSION]

Comment: I found uninstalling IntelliJ and re-installing it on Mac a pain.

Answer (score -1):

You can always uninstall the application completely using an app like ''AppCleaner'' (which removes all additional files of an app) and then install the new version.

Answer (score -1):

I think that if you uninstall application using an app like "AppCleaner" you remote IDEA's config files. I don't sure.

I remove old version of IDEA to trash and copy new version to Application folder. That it. When i started first time a new version i choose use my previously settings and IDEA find it automatically.

I don't think that this is right way, but it works.

Comment: First sentence says " "AppCleaner" you remote IDEA's config files. " Second sentence says the new version can use the previous settings - how as in the first sentence you deleted them? The only conclusion is AppCleaner did not get rid of all the old files as the question asks.

Answer (score -2):

I tried this and worked, give it a try 
https://medium.com/@harittweets/how-to-delete-intellij-idea-community-completely-from-your-mac-beba4012c192

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. We expect answers to be self contained, since if your link goes down, your answer will be useless. Paraphrasing the source and including any relevant information in the answer will ensure it stays relevant